# Dataset logging on Databricks

Tags: databricks

I work for a mid-size online retail outlet. We use Azure Databricks for some data ingestions (Kafka) and for some ETL scenarios. Although Databricks provides some functionality out-of-the-box for tracking size and cost of compute, metrics on the datasets themselves are not immediately available.

Ideally, every data frame that is read or written to/from external storage could be logged. I am imagining, for example, writing a wrapper around spark.read() which computes size of the ingested dataframe and appends a line to an external file. It would then be incumbent on the devs to use this wrapper instead of the native call.

I would prefer that our devs not need to use a custom wrapper for every job/notebook. Is it possible that read/write sizes are already available in internal spark logs? Or maybe through Ganglia?

Looked through Databricks docs, searched online forums, no readily available solutions found.

Comment: Could you elaborate why?

Comment: Does it make sense to use Databricks Overwatch? take a look in the pipeline management specifically here: https://databrickslabs.github.io/overwatch/dataengineer/pipeline_management/